# [Atom][Remote-ftp] Unable to connect ftps/ftpes

Tags: ftp, atom-editor, ftp-client, ftpes

Below two issues I was facing while trying to create ftps connection.

- 421 Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server.
- Uncaught No `protocol` found in connection credential

It was solved after some config changes, which I'm putting in the answer. Same should work for ftpes.

Comment: You added the tag [tag:atom], but your question doesn’t seem to be about the Atom web feed format.

Comment: It's about the atom editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried this and worked (see "secure" and "secureOptions" specifically):

```
{
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "host": "***FTP_HOSTNAME_HERE***",
    "port": 21,
    "user": "***YOUR_USERNAME_HERE***",
    "pass": "***YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE***",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "***REMOTE_PATH_HERE***",
    "secure": true,
    "secureOptions": {"rejectUnauthorized": false, "requestCert": true, "agent": false},
    "connTimeout": 10000, // integer - How long (in milliseconds) to wait for the control connection to be established. Default: 10000
    "pasvTimeout": 10000, // integer - How long (in milliseconds) to wait for a PASV data connection to be established. Default: 10000
    "keepalive": 10000, // integer - How often (in milliseconds) to send a 'dummy' (NOOP) command to keep the connection alive. Default: 10000
    "watch":[]
}
```

Note that "protocol" should always be "ftp" for ftp/ftps/ftpes.

Comment: where do I find these settings? in which file can I edit them?

Comment: Hey, this should go in the configuration in project's .ftpconfig file. See https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp (section "Configuration in project's .ftpconfig file").

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked for me. With vsftpd ssl enabled.

Comment: Qorked for me too, specially the last sentence 'Note that "protocol" should always be "ftp" for ftp/ftps/ftpes.' . Without that sentence I would be still struggling after YEARS of tests.