# [Atom][Remote-ftp][colfax] Unable to connect remote server

Tags: atom-editor

I'm recently trying to work on the Intel® AI DevCloud, please see [Connecting from Linux or a Mac](https://access.colfaxresearch.com/?p=connect#sec-lin).

I can connect the remove server `colfax` via SSH. But I'm not able to set atom-remote-ftp `.ftpconfig` correctly for `colfax`.

Here is what I did:

1. download the linux access key and put it at `key_path`
2. add

   ```
   Host colfax
   User xxxxxx
   IdentityFile key_path
   ProxyCommand ssh -T -i key_path guest@cluster.colfaxresearch.com
   ```
3. logging in use

   ```
   ssh colfax
   ```

Would anyone please let me know what should be the host(?), usr(xxxxxx) and pass("")?

```
{
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "host": "***FTP_HOSTNAME_HERE***",
    "port": 21,
    "user": "***YOUR_USERNAME_HERE***",
    "pass": "***YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE***",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "***REMOTE_PATH_HERE***",
    "secure": true,
    "secureOptions": {"rejectUnauthorized": false, "requestCert": true, "agent": false},
    "connTimeout": 10000, // integer - How long (in milliseconds) to wait for the control connection to be established. Default: 10000
    "pasvTimeout": 10000, // integer - How long (in milliseconds) to wait for a PASV data connection to be established. Default: 10000
    "keepalive": 10000, // integer - How often (in milliseconds) to send a 'dummy' (NOOP) command to keep the connection alive. Default: 10000
    "watch":[]
}
```

code refer to @Sanjay Verma at [[Atom][Remote-ftp] Unable to connect ftps/ftpes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681188/atomremote-ftp-unable-to-connect-ftps-ftpes) . Thank you!

Comment: The link you point to at the top of the post is not useful, it just says "No access".

Comment: Sorry, the link works when logged into colfax. The useful content of the link is shown in @Dilraj Madhava's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the procedure below

```
Host colfax
User uXXXX
IdentityFile ~/Downloads/colfax-access-key-xxxx
ProxyCommand ssh -T -i ~/Downloads/colfax-access-key-xxxx guest@cluster.colfaxresearch.com
```

Set the correct restrictive permissions on the private SSH. To do this, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
chmod 600 ~/Downloads/colfax-access-key-xxxx
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

After the preparation steps above, you should be able to log in to your login node

```
ssh colfax
```

Once your connection is set up, you can copy local files to your login node like this:

```
scp /path/to/local/file colfax:/path/to/remote/directory/
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand how to sync files by scp, it is introduced in the  link. I'm asking how to configure it in atom. I could easily set-up atom using other remote servers but not this colfax...